# fetching span value from html document

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I have following xpath fetched using firefox xpath plugin

```
id('some_id')/x:ul/x:li[4]/x:span
```

using html agility pack I'm able to fetch `id('some_id')/x:ul/x:li[4]`

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//div[@id='some_id']/ul/li[4]").FirstOrDefault();
```

but I dont know how to get this span value.

**update**

```
 <div id="some_id">
    <ul>
      <li><li>
      <li><li>
      <li><li>
      <li>
         Some text
        <span>text I want to grab</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please put more information about the HTML.

Comment: @VictorSigler sorry for delay, question is updated with html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach (without html-agility-pack) would be to use [LINQ2XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). You can use the [XDocument.Descendants method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to take the span element and take it's value:

```
var xml = @" <div id=""some_id"">
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li>
     Some text
    <span>text I want to grab</span>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
Console.WriteLine(doc.Root.Descendants("span").FirstOrDefault().Value);
```

The code can be extended to check if the div element has the matching id, using the [XElement.Attribute property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
Console.WriteLine(doc.Elements("div").Where (e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "some_id").Descendants("span").FirstOrDefault().Value);
```

One drawback of this solution is that the XML structure (HTML, XHTML) needs to be properly closed or else the parsing will fail.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need parse HTML with LINQ2XML, HTMLAgilityPack it's for it and it's more easy to obtain the node in the following way :

```
var html = @" <div id=""some_id"">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li>
      Some text
      <span>text I want to grab</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var value = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("div[@id='some_id']/ul/li/span").InnerText;    
Console.WriteLine(value);
```